# Does GDlib support font fallback to render text with all kind of languages?

Tags: php, fonts, gd

I want to render text in ASCII as well as Ethiopic / Amharic script (but it would be good to support characters for a wide range of languages).

The font Noto is installed on an Ubuntu system using `sudo apt install fonts-noto-core`

How can I output text in mixed languages / support ASCII when printing Ethiopic text using GDLib? Is this even possible?

On the system iself, for example in gedit, it's displayed correctly and font fallback seems to work.

And other option might be to merge all the glyphs into one TTF? Is this possible and necessary for GDlib?

My test code looks like this:

```
<?php

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(200,50);
$font = 'DejaVuSans';

imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 0, 20, imagecolorallocate($image,255,0,0), '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Bold.ttf', "NotoSans-Bold A € ኤ" );
imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 0, 40, imagecolorallocate($image,255,0,0), '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansEthiopic-Bold.ttf', "NotoSans-Ethiopic A € ኤ" );

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo imagepng($image);
```

And produces

[image: Noto sans bold displays ASCII and Euro sign, NotoSansEthiopic only the Ethiopic letter]

I am on PHP8.1 with the following `gd_info()`:

```
array(15) {
  ["GD Version"]=>
  string(5) "2.3.3"
  ["FreeType Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["FreeType Linkage"]=>
  string(13) "with freetype"
  ["GIF Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JPEG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PNG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WBMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XPM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XBM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WebP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["BMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["AVIF Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["TGA Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: As for the workaround, I found https://superuser.com/a/1382162/38752

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I merged the font myself as described [by satish](https://satish.com.in/20211205/).

```
apt install python3-nototools fonttools
cp /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nototools/merge_fonts.py ~/merge_fonts.py
```

Use this fontlist

```
# file names to be merged
files = [
    "NotoSans-Bold.ttf",
    "NotoSansEthiopic-Bold.ttf",
]
```

Then execute

```
PYTHONPATH='.' python3 ~/merge_fonts.py -d /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/ -o ~/NotoSansWithEthiopic.ttf
```

Using this font in GDlib works.